# Как сохранить число в память устройства а потом его прочитать. Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Как сохранить число в память устройства а потом его прочитать.
Есть число которое необходимо запомнить и при следующем запуске устройства прочитать.

Comment: @YungBlade Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences

Очень простой способ 
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html